# How to decode byte array to codePoint

Tags: java, character-encoding

Java decoders provide easy to way to decode `byte[]` into `chars[]`, but as we all know, UTF8 char can consist of multiple java chars.

Because of that API in java started to use `int codePoint` as a replacement, but there seems to be missing functionality of decoding bytes into codePoints.

My goal is to decode bytes at given offset into **single** codePoint, *without creating any intermediate objects like* `ArrayBuffer`.

Is there any efficient way to achieve that?

Comment: Read this article: http://bjoern.hoehrmann.de/utf-8/decoder/dfa/.  The example code is in C, but you should be able to figure out what it is doing.

Comment: The String functions work on sequences UTF-16 code units. What are you going to do with codepoints/UTF-32 code units?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java itself gives you that tool. Look at class `Character`, method [public static int codePointAt(char[] a, int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt-char:A-int-) (and its overloaded versions) That should help you. Also, when I work with character set related problems I found it very helpful to use a utility that converts String into sequence of Unicodes and vise versa

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library that contains this  Utility is called MgntUtils and can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc. Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html). Here is the link to an article that describes the MgntUtils Open source library: [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)